# The program prints unwanted things

Tags: c, string

Why the following program saves the + sign even loop should end when she sees this sign.

My code-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
char str[10]= "2+48*46+1";
char str1[10];
int i,j = 0;

for(i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
    if(str[i] == '*')
    {
        while(str1[j-1] != '+' )
        {
            str1[j] = str[i+1];
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }
}
printf("%s\n",str1);
}
```

Target clearing the numbers after the multiplication sign up to + sign.

Thank helpers who could tell me why the software keeps + sign and suggest me way to fix it (:

Comment: It doesn't -- prints `46`.

Comment: It prints 46+ But I need it to print only 46

Comment: I changed it to while (str [i]! = '+') But it's still the same thing

Answer (score 3):

You access `str1[-1]` which invokes undefined behaviour.

You don't null terminate `str1`, so you print whatever values are in `str1` after `46` too.
You copy the `+` into the string, so that appears, but there could be other non-zero bytes in `str1` after that. It would be better not to copy the `+` and to null terminate the string.

```
j = 0;
while (str[i+j] != '+')
    str1[j++] = str[i+j];
str1[j++] = '\0';
printf("%s\n", str1);
```

Answer (score 1):

It keeps the plus sign because you break out of the while loop when the target string has a plus as the last character.  You should test the source string instead - something like

```
while(str[i+1] != '+' )
    {
        str1[j++] = str[++i];
    }
```

Comment: I'd shorten that by making `str[++i]` and not needing to do an increment later.

Comment: ...or do both the increments around the assignment: `str1[j++] = str[++i]`

Comment: so if it works you should `Accept` the answer. your question is Solved!

Answer (score 1):

You code is incorrect. Because (j-1) may be negative and str1 is not initialized.